# ReplacementRange.value = ReplacementRange.value bug

Tags: vba

I have a bug in my code (that I found a work around for), but I was hoping you could help me determine what the problem is. Here is the code that doesn't work:

```
Sub replacewithnumbers1()

Dim ReplacementRange As Range

Set ReplacementRange = Range("a2:c2")
Set ReplacementRange = Range(ReplacementRange, ReplacementRange.End(xlDown))

ReplacementRange.value = ReplacementRange.value

End Sub
```

When I run this, it works find for A2:C17, but everything below that gets changed to "#N/A".

Now here is the code that works:

```
Dim ReplacementRange As Range

Set ReplacementRange = Range("A2")
Set ReplacementRange = Range(ReplacementRange, ReplacementRange.End(xlDown))

ReplacementRange.value = ReplacementRange.value

Set ReplacementRange = Range("b2")
Set ReplacementRange = Range(ReplacementRange, ReplacementRange.End(xlDown))
ReplacementRange.value = ReplacementRange.value

Set ReplacementRange = Range("c2")
Set ReplacementRange = Range(ReplacementRange, ReplacementRange.End(xlDown))
ReplacementRange.value = ReplacementRange.value

Set ReplacementRange = Range("I2")
Set ReplacementRange = Range(ReplacementRange, ReplacementRange.End(xlDown))

ReplacementRange.value = ReplacementRange.value
```

All I did was break it down into more steps (one for each column), and then it works. When I do two columns at once I get the same error (either A:B or B:C). It always stops at row 17, and I don't know why. Care to help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: None of the code acts as you say it should for me, which version of Excel are you using? Also, I can't see how it ever did work, as you are simply setting the the value of your `ReplacementRange` to the exact same value..

Comment: Could you please share a screen of the relevant sheet part, with row 17?

Comment: I'll be posting screens, and a link to the tables in a moment- I am using Excel 2010.

Comment: The reason I'm using     replacement range is to change values stored as text into numbers.

Comment: Stupid question- how do I post the file/screenshot?

Comment: Screens using Jing software, files using dropbox or any similar service - and just drop a link here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out why it was behaving this way (I think). There was a filter on the data set so that row 16 wasn't visible, and when I take the filter off- it runs correctly. Sorry it was a little anti-climactic.

Comment: That's why I asked to share screen)) Anyway glad to know you solved the issue on your own. You'll be able to accept your own answer in a few days.

Comment: I had no idea that this was a thing. Out of idle curiosity- what causes the code to break when there are hidden rows?

Comment: I'm not sure, but perhaps the very same reason when you try to copy the whole **filtered** column and paste it back to the same location - you'll see "The command cannot be used on multiple selections". It seems that hidden cells break contiguous range, and your code works only for such ranges.

Comment: Weird, I know if I do a for statement (as in For each cell in ReplacementRange- it will hit hidden cells as well as visable cells). Maybe when I get more time on my hands I'll look into it more.

Comment: is removing filters before macro work is an option? Try `ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False`

Comment: I actually run a macro before that puts the filter on first, so I've just started running the filters second. So yes it is. Thanks!